# How to add and draw edge labels in networkx correctly?

Tags: label, python-3.6, networkx

I am adding labels with

```
G.add_edge(node1, node2, label=label)
```

drawing with

```
pos = nx.spring_layout(G)

nx.draw(G, pos)
nx.draw_networkx_edge_labels(G, pos)
```

and getting

[image]

which I don't want. I don't want label look like `{'label': 'a"}` I want it be just `a`.

Is it possible? I saw examples, where labels were passing into draw function, which is not good for me. I want labels to be stored in the graph and displayed later.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the `edge_labels` argument to specify what to draw. Example:

```
>>> import networkx as nx
>>> G = nx.Graph()
>>> G.add_edge(1, 2, label='a')
>>> pos = nx.spring_layout(G)                                                    
>>> nx.draw(G, pos)                                                              
>>> nx.draw_networkx_edge_labels(G,pos,edge_labels=nx.get_edge_attributes(G,'label'))
{(1, 2): Text(0,0,'a')}
```

[image]

Comment: how to offset the "a" above perpendicular to the arrow? so that it doesn't lie "on" the arrow, but slightly above it?